# How to change the number of rows displayed in the nstableview dynamically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

How do we change the number of rows that is being displayed in the table view dynamically based on certain condition.

I have a requirement which needs the table view not to display any empty rows or whitespace.

How to do this?

Thnx in advance.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize searchField;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
// Insert code here to initialize your application

}


-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (nil!= self)
{
_arrayContents= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"as",@"sd",@"dfg",@"fh",@"sdf",@"ret",@"sdf",@"dsfxc",@"awert",@"xsdfcvg", nil];
_searchedArrayContents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_arrayContents count]];

_menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"123",@"1231234",@"235435",@"5345345", nil];
}
    return  self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
//    [_menuTableView setHidden:YES];
//    [[[_menuTableView superview] superview] setHidden:YES];

[[[_menuTableView superview] superview] setFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 0, 234, 1000)];
[[_menuTableView superview] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];

[_menuTableView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{

if (aTableView==_menuTableView)
{
    return  [_menuArray count];
}


if ([[searchField stringValue] length]>0 || [[_tokenField stringValue] length]>0 || [[_textField stringValue] length]>0)
{ 
    return [_searchedArrayContents count];
}
if (aTableView==_tableView)
{
    return [_arrayContents count];
}
return  0;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn         *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{

if (aTableView==_menuTableView)
{
    return  [_menuArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

if ([[searchField stringValue] length]>0 || [[_tokenField stringValue] length]>0)
{
    return [_searchedArrayContents objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

if (aTableView==_tableView)
{
    return [_arrayContents objectAtIndex:rowIndex] ;
}
return nil;
}
```

I have tried to change the frame position of the TableView dynamically in the above code. But its not changing the frame. It remains in the same position where I had dragged and dropped in the Interface Builder.

Comment: You need to change the data source of the NSTableView programmatically and you need to refresh the table view whenever the source change.

Comment: What have you done so far?  If you show some of your code, you wouldn't confuse those who try to help you.

Comment: @Ganapathy : I am changing the datasource accordingly. The requirement I have is I dont want to display the unused rows of the table view. It should only display the actual no. of elements present in the datasource without displaying any empty rows.

Comment: @TBlue: I have edited the question and posted the code. I am actually trying to change the frame postion so that I can limit the no. of rows to be displayed in the table view. But it doesnot change the size at all.

Answer (score 0):

For Displaying Number of rows -

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section         {
return [nameArray count];
```

}

For Adjusting height of tableView -

```
    UITableView *automotiveTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    automotiveTable.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,(70+([nameArray count]*60)+70)*h/480);
    automotiveTable.delegate = self;
    automotiveTable.dataSource = self;
    automotiveTable.backgroundView = backgroundImage;
    [self.view addSubview:automotiveTable];
```

Comment: I have tableview present in the IB hence I cannot use this approach. Can I resize the tableview based on the contents of the table view?

Comment: This is a MAC application and I tried using content size, but there is no property or method associated with NSTableView on mac.

Comment: UITableView != NSTableView

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i have understood your question,
If you are trying to resize tableview according to its content try this,

1.Get The number of rows required

2.Multiply it with row hight

3.Set the table view hight to the hight you got.

4.You can choose to provide min,and max hight for your tableview too.

Have a nice day:)

Comment: Actually I am doing it. To do this I need to use set frame on tableview which I am doing also. But even after I do it, the table view doesnot change. It remains at the same place and doesnot get resized. I am creating the tableview using Interface builder.

Comment: IB provides tableview with enclosing scrollView so you might have to resize it too.

Comment: I have tried resizing all the views. Tableview, ClipView, Scrollview. If I programmatically create the table view, I can resize it, if its from IB ,I am not able to resize it.

Comment: Can you post your code? it might help us understanding what is going wrong

Comment: I have put the code in the question itself. Thats all the code I have written along with .h file.

Comment: I don see any resizing of tableview in your code ,Are you reffering to -(void)awakeFromNib ? Are you sure it is a right place to do that?It will get called only once before your delegate/datasource methods:)

Comment: Try this [[_menuTableView enclosingScrollView] setFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 100, 100)]; first in your awakeFromNib and the move it to appropriate place, cheers:)